# GridView which keeps all elements instead of building them once on-screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a grid view which is showing the heal status of many different services, and coloring them and/or auto-opening a webpage when the service goes down. The problem is that the elements which are off the screen are not being checked, which is more efficient, but not what is desired in this case.

I guess it's behaving similarly to the RecyclerView in android?

I want to be building the widgets which are checking service health even when they are not visible on the screen.

Currently the services don't start being checked until the moment I scroll them into the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are currently using the `GridView.builder` constructor, I recommend using the "normal" `GridView` constructor (with a `children` property). Since `GridView.builder` only builds the elements currently visible for efficiency reasons, the elements that are not rendered on the screen won't run your back end logic.

For more information, see the [official docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView/GridView.builder.html):

> [GridView.builder] constructor is appropriate for grid views with a large (or infinite) number of children because the builder is called only for those children that are actually visible.

[Here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html) you'll find alternatives:

> The most commonly used grid layouts are GridView.count, which creates a layout with a fixed number of tiles in the cross axis, and GridView.extent, which creates a layout with tiles that have a maximum cross-axis extent.